# How to unbox values returned by javascript (nashorn) in Java object?

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

I have the following program, which executes Javascript in Java (nashorn) . The Javascript code is returning an object.

```
public Object execute(){
        ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine e = sem.getEngineByName("nashorn");  
        Invocable invocable = (Invocable)e;
        ScriptEngineFactory f = e.getFactory();
        Object result;
        try {
            String statement = "function fetch(value, count) { count++ ; return {'value': value,'count' : count} }; } ; ";
            CompiledScript cs = ((Compilable)e).compile(statement);
            cs.eval();
            result = invocable.invokeFunction("fetch", 10,2);

        }   
        catch (Exception se ) {
            String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
            System.out.println(version);
            result = "script exception ";
        }
```

How do I access the object values in my result object in Java? 
Initially, I tried using `result.toString()` to get results. Seems to `return [Object Object]`

Is there a way, where I could return the results to `result` object such that I could get values equivalent to `result.value` , and `result.count` (similar to Javascript) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't return a `JSObject` from the JavaScript function. Valid would be

```
{
  value: value,
  count : count
}
```

So you could use this Java code.

```
package de.lhorn.so;

import javax.script.Compilable;
import javax.script.CompiledScript;
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject;

public class SOPlayground {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SOPlayground sop = new SOPlayground();
        JSObject jso = sop.execute();
        System.out.println("value=" + jso.getMember("value"));
        System.out.println("count=" + jso.getMember("count"));
    }

    public JSObject execute() throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        final ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        final Compilable compilable = (Compilable) engine;
        final Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;

        final String statement =
          "function fetch(value, count) { count++ ; return {value: value, count : count} };";
        final CompiledScript compiled = compilable.compile(statement);

        compiled.eval();

        return (JSObject) invocable.invokeFunction("fetch", 10, 2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
value=10
count=3.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! JSObject saved my day. I was using ScriptObjectMirror which is a total no no in my case.

Comment: @Rahul The Nahorn `JSObject` interface is implemented by the `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror` actually returned by `invokeFunction`.

Comment: I am currently using a cast to `Map<String, Object>`, which works fine because `ScriptObjectMirror` actually implements that interface... Should I use `JSObject` instead? I haven't found clear documentation on this yet... The `Invocable` interface just defines `Object` as return type, which is pretty useless.

Answer (score 7):

If the return value of your program is a JavaScript object, you should be able to cast it to `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject` in Java and then use its methods (e.g. `getMember()`) to query and manipulate it.